# How to remove a element from an Array in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a small, yet important issue with my code that uses Mongoose/MongoDB. I can't seem to be able to use `$pull` or `$pullAll` in `Model.findOneAndUpdate({})`.

My code is the following:

```
db?.updateOne({ $pull: {
                AutoRole: {
                    Roles: [value],
                }
            }
            });
```

And this is my Model schema:

```
const guildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    GuildID: String,
    AuditChannel: String,
    AutoRole: {
        Roles: Array
    },

});
```

So far I'm out of ideas on how to make it work. I was wondering if I was doing it wrong, but I can't seem to find what I'm doing exactly wrong.

Comment: I think it's `$pull : { "AutoRole.Roles": ... }`

Comment: Lemme give that one a try.

Comment: @CollinD Doesnt work, still.

```
db?.updateOne({
                $pull: {
                    "AutoRole.Roles": [value]
                }
            });
```

Comment: Doesn't $pull just take a value rather than an array? I can never remember how mongo operators work off the top of my head, but maybe remove the `[]`

Comment: Hm, lemme give it a try.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!

If you want, post it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct syntax here is:

```
{
  $pull: {
    "AutoRole.Roles": value
  }
}
```